# Force to fetch latest released version of maven dependency using Ant artifacts in build.xml

Tags: maven, build, ant

In Ant build included the maven dependency

```
<artifact:dependencies> 
    <dependency groupId="dev.sample" artifactId="test" type="zip" version="1.3"/>
</artifact:dependencies>
```

Some time we upload manually same version of artifacts in remote repository with some changes.

In .m2 already same version available, it is not downloading the updated one from remote repository.

Is that any possible way to update this specific artifact in local .m2 from remote repository during build ?

Comment: First of all, it is usually a bad idea to replace versions in a Maven repository. That said: you can just delete the file from your local repository and Maven will resolve it again.

Comment: @JFabianMeier which out removing manually no option for override evertime ?

Comment: Why should you? Replacing versions in this way is really a bad thing. If you want to "manipulate" an artifact and redeploy it, use a new version like `1.3-patched`